# Почему массив изменяется при изменении его составляющих?

Tags: list, python-3.7, tuple, variable

```
[1] n = 3
[2] deck = [1,2,3]
[3] piles = [[],[4,5]]
[4] ndp = [(1,[1,2,3,4],[[],[4,5]])]
    
[5] if (n, deck, piles) not in ndp:
[6]     k = (n,deck,piles)
[7]     ndp.append(k)

[8] print(ndp)
>>> [(1, [1, 2, 3, 4], [[], [4, 5]]), (3, [1, 2, 3], [[], [4, 5]])]

[9] piles[1].append(deck.pop(0))
[10] print(ndp)
>>> [(1, [1, 2, 3, 4], [[], [4, 5]]), (3, [2, 3], [[], [4, 5, 1]])]
```

Почему массив `ndp` изменяется после изменения `piles` в строке `[9]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив `ndp` изменился после извлечения первого элемента из `deck`. А `ndp` хранит в себе ссылку на `deck`.

Поэтому в массив стоит добавлять копии объектов (через `copy.deepcopy(piles)` и `copy.deepcopy(deck)`).

Comment: Спасибо. Ещё проблему можно решить без импортов, изменив строку `[6]` на: `k = (n+0, deck+[], piles+[])`.